# How remove '1' '2' '3' 'next' 'prev' in BXSLIDER

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I use bxslider often, however, when I try to put it in an existing webpage, it shows  '1' '2' '3' 'next' 'prev' 
I've already removed the 'next' and 'prev'. But the '1' '2' and '3' (referring to the 3 sliding images' still shows in the page

[example page with this problem](http://astyle.home.xs4all.nl/beautyfarm2003/start.html)

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            speed: 3000,
            controls: false,
            auto: true,
            autoControls: false,
            touchEnabled: true
            }); 
        });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

As it says [in the docs](http://bxslider.com/options), you need to disable the pager:

```
pager: false
```

Making the full call look like this:

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        speed: 3000,
        controls: false,
        auto: true,
        autoControls: false,
        touchEnabled: true,
        pager: false // <-------
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: You're welcome. Make sure you know what bxslider can do, especially since you use it often.